# Issues with displays timeseries with streamlit

Tags: python, spyder, forecasting, arima, streamlit

im trying to displays forecasting timeseries using streamlit,but im stuck because i dont know what should i do first,bcs for timeseries im using jupyter notebook and i got confused how to displays it with streamlit(issue with stationary,etc).Can you guys give me reference or something? thank you!
here is my code in spyder ( im just showing raw data and the graph and yeah got stuck with deploy my forecasting)

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf,pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import warnings                                  # `do not disturbe` mode
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

st.title('Forecasting Harga KCL')

DATE_COLUMN = 'month'


@st.cache
def load_data(nrows):
    data = pd.read_csv('kcl.csv', nrows=nrows)
    lowercase = lambda x: str(x).lower()
    data.rename(lowercase, axis='columns', inplace=True)
    data[DATE_COLUMN] = pd.to_datetime(data[DATE_COLUMN])
    data.set_index('month', inplace=True)
    data =data['price']
    return data

data_load_state = st.text('Loading data...')
data = load_data(300)
data_load_state.text("Done! (using st.cache)")

if st.checkbox('Show raw data'):
    st.subheader('Raw data')
    st.write(data)

st.subheader('Plot harga')
st.line_chart(data)

st.subheader('Harga Prediksi')
```

about this code below i dont know if its right because the timeseries doesnt pass the stationary test at all and the forecasting might go wrong

```
data = data [66:]
for a in range(1,30):
    model = ARIMA (data, order = (1, 1, 1))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=False)
    yhat = model_fit.predict(len(data), len(data), typ='levels')
    data = data.append(yhat)
    st.write(yhat)
    # We display the prediction to see when it passes 0
if st.checkbox('Show hasil prediksi'):
    st.subheader('data prediction')
    st.write(yhat)
```

i hope you all can understand me with my lack of understanding and making question! thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have two questions - one about streamlit and one about time series stationarity.

If you're trying to serve a streamlit model locally, just do `streamlit run my_file.py` where you insert the path to your file. You must have streamlit installed on your machine/virtual environment. If you're trying to deploy your app on server, check out the streamlit deployment guides [here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-guide-wiki/5099). Heroku is maybe the simplest free deployment.

If your data aren't stationary and there is a seasonality component, you'll want SARIMA instead of ARIMA.

If you want to try to automatically select values for SARIMA using p,d,q,P,D,Q or do any transforms prior to fitting, [sktime's autoarima](https://www.sktime.org/en/latest/api_reference/modules/auto_generated/sktime.forecasting.arima.AutoARIMA.html#sktime.forecasting.arima.AutoARIMA) can be helpful. It wraps pmdarima, which uses statsmodels SARIMAX.

Forecasting Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) by Rob Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos is a great free ebook on time series.

Comment: thank you so much you help me a alot! but sorry what i mean before is display the graph not deploy..i got confused between display and deploy..and yeah what i really want to ask is in jupyter notebook i do all the things for forecasting but what about in streamlit(im using spyder)do i have to check the stationary,the hypothesis,acf pacf and all the stuff about stationary in order to display my forecasting? thank you once again!

Comment: before im trying to do all stationary things but i got an error like this" loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type function which has no callable log method"

Comment: You can just use a Python script to check stationarity if you don't want to use a Jupyter notebook. Generally, I'd just do all that interactively in a Jupyter notebook. I'd only use streamlit if you wanted to have an app that showed people how to check for stationarity.